# Mouse Hover function to refer different <div id> on same Vue.js function

Tags: html, vue.js, vuex

I have two div id in ".html" file where I've defined mouseover property.

```
<div id="app">
<img class="img-responsive img-full" v-bind:src="imgData" @mouseover="imgData = imgData_1">
</div>

<div id="app1">
<img class="img-responsive img-full" v-bind:src="imgData_c" @mouseover="imgData_c = imgData_a">
</div>
```

In my app.js I've mentioned the below code

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
  data:{
  imgData:'img/blog_grid_3.jpg',
  imgData_1:'img/blog_grid_1.jpg',
  imgData_2:'img/blog_grid_2.jpg'
}
})

var app1 = new Vue({
    el:'#app1',
  data:{
  imgData_a:'img/blog_grid_1.jpg',
  imgData_b:'img/blog_grid_3.jpg',
  imgData_c:'img/blog_grid_2.jpg'
}
})
```

Is it possible if I do a mouse hover in the image on div id="app" (1st 'div') then the image on div id="app1" (2nd 'div') change?.

Comment: You could create an event handler in `app1` and wire that up to an even in `app`.

Comment: You could use a directive here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in event bus in a Vue instance. Listen to changes and emit events on a third Vue instance. You just need to make sure, that you can access this third Vue intance in both of your apps. Here is an article to read more about this feature: [article](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)

Here is an example on how to use such an EventBus:

```js
const EventBus = new Vue();

// subscribe to the event 'some-event' and add a handler function
EventBus.$on('some-event', data => {
  console.log('"some-event" was called via event.');
  console.log(data);
});

// actually emit the event with some payload
EventBus.$emit('some-event', { test: 123 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

---

You may also want to ask yourself if it is really necessary to have two separate Vue instances running. Many use cases can be handled within the same Vue instance. You might want to look into topics about components and routing.

Communicating between components is also possible with a global state. You could e.g. use Vuex to have your state at one place and access this global state from your components.